# Converting roman/arabic numerals higher than 4000

Tags: python, function

I am going to write a program that converts roman numerals to arabic and vice-versa. I already have a working code for converting numbers under 4000. For roman numerals higher than or equal to 4000 the new way to write them is that a parenthesis means multiplied by 1000. So for example 4000 is (IV), 6010 is (VI)X etc. Thankful for answer.
Daniel

Edit: Ok so to clear up the problem. There is no roman numeral bigger than 3999, so a method to write bigger numbers is to put a bar (or a parenthesis) around a roman numeral meaning that numeral should be multiplied by 1000

The function right now:

```
def intToRoman(integer):
    rlist = romanList = [(1000, "M"),(900, "CM"),(500, "D"),(400, "CD"),(100, "C"),(90, "XC"),(50, "L"),(40, "XL"),(10, "X"),(9, "IX"),(5, "V"),(4, "IV"),(1, "I")]
    romanResult = ""
    for wholeNumber in rlist:
            while integer >= wholeNumber[0]:
                    integer -= wholeNumber[0]
                    romanResult += wholeNumber[1]
    return romanResult

def romanToInt(numeral):
    rlist = romanList = [(1000, "M"),(900, "CM"),(500, "D"),(400, "CD"),(100, "C"),(90, "XC"),(50, "L"),(40, "XL"),(10, "X"),(9, "IX"),(5, "V"),(4, "IV"),(1, "I")]
        index = 0
        intResult = 0
        for integer, romanNumeral in rlist:
            while numeral[index : index + len(romanNumeral)] == romanNumeral:
                intResult += integer
                index += len(romanNumeral)
```

Comment: There are *no* roman numeral symbols for values over 1000, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals. [A bar was placed over the digits instead](http://www.jimloy.com/arith/roman0.htm).

Comment: [dive into python](http://www.diveintopython3.net/regular-expressions.html) has a whole chapter on this

Comment: The problem is that I need to write number bigger than 4000 with bars or parenthesis meaning *1000

Comment: And what about numbers over 4 million?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need two functions. One for numbers higher than 4000 and one for numbers below.

```
def smallIntToRoman(integer):
    rlist = romanList = [(1000, "M"),(900, "CM"),(500, "D"),(400, "CD"),(100, "C"),(90, "XC"),(50, "L"),(40, "XL"),(10, "X"),(9, "IX"),(5, "V"),(4, "IV"),(1, "I")]
    romanResult = ""
    for wholeNumber in rlist:
            while integer >= wholeNumber[0]:
                    integer -= wholeNumber[0]
                    romanResult += wholeNumber[1]
    return romanResult

def bigIntToRoman(integer):
    thousands, rest = divmod(integer, 1000)
    return "({}){}".format(smallIntToRoman(thousands), smallIntToRoman(rest))

def intToRoman(integer):
    if integer >= 4000:
        return bigIntToRoman(integer)
    else:
        return smallIntToRoman(integer)


def smallRomanToInt(numeral):
    rlist = romanList = [(1000, "M"),(900, "CM"),(500, "D"),(400, "CD"),(100, "C"),(90, "XC"),(50, "L"),(40, "XL"),(10, "X"),(9, "IX"),(5, "V"),(4, "IV"),(1, "I")]
    if checkIfRomanNumeral(numeral) is False:
        pass
    elif checkIfRomanNumeral(numeral) is True:
        index = 0
        intResult = 0
        for integer, romanNumeral in rlist:
            while numeral[index : index + len(romanNumeral)] == romanNumeral:
                intResult += integer
                index += len(romanNumeral)

def romainToInt(numeral):
    if len(numeral) == 0:
        return None
    int_parts = numeral[1:].split(')') # Better done with regex
    if len(int_parts) == 1:
        return smallRomainToInt(numeral)
    elif len(int_parts) == 2:
        big = smallRomainToInt(int_parts[1])
        small = smallRomainToInt(int_parts[0])
        if big is None or small is None:
            return None
        else:
            return big * 1000 + small
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: So how are numbers over 1,000,000 now handled? Why the separate functions when you could recurse or loop?

Comment: For simplicity's sake. Even though you can indeed use recursion. Using this system one can go to 4,002,999 (3999*1000+3999). I honestly have no idea how it is supposed to handle bigger numbers.

Comment: Which is why we are asking the OP for clarification.

Comment: now that I think about it, you must take care when using recursion, say you try to convert 5000001. The first iteration will detect that the number is bigger than 5000 and parse its two parts 5000 and 1. On the second iteration, it will try to convert 5000 which is again bigger than 4000 resulting in a double parenthesis which is from what I have read not correct.

Comment: No, you use `divmod(num, 4000)` and process the remainder each iteration.

Comment: this is my first python course so I dont think I need a more advanced code than this. I actually have no idea if it is even possible to make bigger roman numerals than that so we can skip that. Thank you very much for the help!
Edit:
Shouldnt the index number be switched in this segment:
    big = smallRomainToInt(int_parts[1])
    small = smallRomainToInt(int_parts[0])

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`divmod()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#divmod) to produce both the whole divisor and the remainder in one step:

```
>>> divmod(45, 10)
(4, 5)
```

That's 4 times 10 and a remainder of 5.

With that function it both producing simple roman numeral output and roman numerals handling  exponents of 4000 becomes much simpler. Each higher exponent is wrapped in increasing levels of parenthesis:

```
romanList = [
    (1000, "M"), (900, "CM"),
    (500, "D"), (400, "CD"), 
    (100, "C"), (90, "XC"), 
    (50, "L"), (40, "XL"),
    (10, "X"), (9, "IX"),
    (5, "V"), (4, "IV"),
    (1, "I")
]

def intToRoman(integer):
    result = []
    parenscount = 0
    while integer:
        integer, num = divmod(integer, 4000)
        romanResult = ""
        for value, rchar in romanList:
            count, num = divmod(num, value)
            romanResult += count * rchar
        if romanResult:
            result.append('{}{}{}'.format(
                '(' * parenscount, romanResult, ')' * parenscount))
        parenscount += 1
    return ' '.join(result[::-1])
```

Because we add roman numerals in order from smallest to largest in `result`, you do need to reverse the list at the end when joining the strings together; `result[::-1]` reverses a list by using a negative step.

I moved `romanList` to a global, we can reuse it later when parsing roman numerals back to numbers.

Demo:

```
>>> intToRoman(2013)
'MMXIII'
>>> intToRoman(3999)
'MMMCMXCIX'
>>> intToRoman(4000)
'(I)'
>>> intToRoman(4010230)
'(MII) MMCCXXX'
>>> intToRoman(237310230)
'((XIV)) (MMMCCCXXVII) MMCCXXX'
```

The other direction, then, we can simplify and multiply the result by 4000 each time we find a  closing parenthesis:

```
def romanToInt(numeral):
    result = 0
    while numeral:
        preparse_length = len(numeral)
        groupresult = 0
        numeral = numeral.lstrip('( ')  # remove opening parens and spaces
        for value, rchar in romanList:
            while numeral.startswith(rchar):
                groupresult += value
                numeral = numeral[len(rchar):]
        if len(numeral) == preparse_length:
            # No valid numerals found, not a Roman numeral then
            raise ValueError(
                'ValueError: invalid literal for romanToInt: {!r}'.format(numeral))
        while numeral[:1] == ')':
            groupresult *= 4000
            numeral = numeral[1:]
        result += groupresult
    return result
```

Demo:

```
>>> romanToInt('MMXIII')
2013
>>> romanToInt('MMMCMXCIX')
3999
>>> romanToInt('(I)')
4000
>>> romanToInt('(MII) MMCCXXX')
4010230
>>> romanToInt('((XIV)) (MMMCCCXXVII) MMCCXXX')
237310230
>>> romanToInt('booh')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 14, in romanToInt
ValueError: ValueError: invalid literal for romanToInt: 'booh'
```