# Remove Roman numbers

Tags: python, regex

I have a text which contains latin numbers, like I, II etc which cometimes followed by dot (I.) and some other times without a dot (I). I want to remove them by using regular expressions in python. I can define the following function, but seems quite basic and takes lots of time. I was wondering if there any other way that I could remove them?

```
def clean(text):
  text = text.replace("Ι.", '&')
  text = text.replace("II.", '&')
  text = text.replace("III.", '&')
  text = text.replace("IV.", '&')
  text = text.replace("V.", '&')
  text = text.replace("VI.", '&')
  text = text.replace("VII.", '&')
  text = text.replace("VIII.", '&')
  text = text.replace("IX.", '&')
  text = text.replace("X.", '&')
  text = text.replace("XI.", '&')
  text = text.replace("XII.", '&')
  text = text.replace("XIII", '&')
  text = text.replace("XIV.", '&')

  return text
```

Comment: you could use re.sub with a pattern from this page followed by an optional dot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267399/how-do-you-match-only-valid-roman-numerals-with-a-regular-expression

Comment: Since the dot is optional, your actual text will be important here. How will you distinguish between `I` for the number one and `I` the personal pronoun?

Comment: Just do `text = text.replace('Ι', '&').replace('V', '&').replace('X', '&')` will replace all occurrences of I, V or X with &

Comment: George, did you use the first `Ι` example deliberately or is it a copy/paste from some source? This is not the ASCII `I`, it is a *‎0399 GREEK CAPITAL LETTER IOTA*. Now, the question becomes rather unclear: do you want to match all possible variations of letters similar to those used in Roman numbers? Actually, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267399/how-do-you-match-only-valid-roman-numerals-with-a-regular-expression) will work for ASCII Roman numbers.

Comment: @Viktor, thank you so much for your note. I guess this came up because I was doing copy paste.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```py
def clean(text):
    pattern = r"\b(?=[MDCLXVIΙ])M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})([IΙ]X|[IΙ]V|V?[IΙ]{0,3})\b\.?"
    return re.sub(pattern, '&', text)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/YetrZ4/2/). Add more non-standard letters like `Ι` if necessary.

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [MDCLXVIΙ]          any character of: 'M', 'D', 'C', 'L',
                             'X', 'V', 'I', '&', '#', '9', '2', '1',
                             ';'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  M{0,4}                   'M' (between 0 and 4 times (matching the
                           most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    CM                       'CM'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    CD                       'CD'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    D?                       'D' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    C{0,3}                   'C' (between 0 and 3 times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    XC                       'XC'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    XL                       'XL'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    L?                       'L' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    X{0,3}                   'X' (between 0 and 3 times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [IΙ]                any character of: 'I', '&', '#', '9',
                             '2', '1', ';'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    X                        'X'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [IΙ]                any character of: 'I', '&', '#', '9',
                             '2', '1', ';'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    V                        'V'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    V?                       'V' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [IΙ]{0,3}           any character of: 'I', '&', '#', '9',
                             '2', '1', ';' (between 0 and 3 times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.?                      '.' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Your code is very good but I faced a problem in this case test2 = "roman MCMLXXXVIII. roman XVII notroman MADXXXL invalid MILLI", the output is 'roman & roman & notroman &ADXXXL invalid &LLI'. However, the code of VPfB deals with this problem. Could I adopt our algo to avoid this case?

Comment: @George I think I missed the closing word boundary. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Pleae, read first this [How do you match only valid roman numerals with a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267399/how-do-you-match-only-valid-roman-numerals-with-a-regular-expression)

If any regexp shown there is good enough, please use that. If not read on.

---

Hope this helps, but it is not complete. You have to write a test for valid roman numbers, because the regexp finds any combination of roman numerals. Related: [Check if an input is a valid roman numeral](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20973546/check-if-an-input-is-a-valid-roman-numeral)

```
import re

MAYBE_ROMAN = re.compile(r'(\b[MDCLXVI]+\b)(\.)?', re.I)  # I = ignore case (optional)

def is_roman(num):
    # TODO!
    return True

def replace_roman(match):
    roman = match.group(1)
    if is_roman(roman):
        return '&' # replacement
    return roman # unchanged

test = "roman MCMLXXXVIII. roman XVII notroman MADXXXL invalid MILLI"
result = re.sub(MAYBE_ROMAN, replace_roman, test)
print(result)
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help!!! In MAYBE_ROMAN I don't understand why we need 're.I', is it possible to explain me more?

Comment: @George It is an optional "ignore case". You decide, if you need the `re.I` to match also the lower case like `(iii.)` or not.